# how to pass a variable from javascript to yii2 function

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have a dropdown list of company names. When I select companies from it and click on 'get info' button I should get rows with selected company id.

**View**

```
$typeahead = Select2::widget([
    'id' => 'front_companies_select',
    'name' => 'state_10',
    'data' => $companyNameList,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Select ...',
        'multiple' => true
    ],
]);
 <?= Html::SubmitButton( 'Get info', [ 'class' => 'btn btn-success' , 'id' =>'getinfo']) ?>
```

**Javascript file**

```
$("#getinfo").click(function(){
        var id = $("#front_companies_select option:selected").val();
        console.log(id); //want to pass this id in controller as ap parameter actionInfo($id)
     });
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionVerify($id)  // want to get id here
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $connection = Yii::$app->db;
        $model = $connection->createCommand("SELECT * FROM companies where id=$id");
$users = $model->queryOne();
            return $this->redirect(['companies/index']);   //want to show rows in this gridview    
    }
```

Can any one fix it? I am stuck with it..

Comment: you should look at ajax  .and . pjax

Comment: can you give some links regarding  or an example how to pass the parameter.. sorry but i am new to this ..

Comment: these are basic elements  so you can easy find some ref using google

Comment: for example: [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/programming-with-yii2-using-ajax--cms-26663)

Comment: just want to get selected companies rows is there any other way other than above code. still not fixed it.

Comment: So you want display selected details on current page or new page

Comment: Did it work to you? can select my answer as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that you're in a controller without any URL params you can do something like this:

```
$("#getinfo").click(function(){
        var id = $("#front_companies_select option:selected").val();
        window.location.href = 'verify?id=' + id;
```

});

Otherwise you have to build the URL and passing it to `window.location`

Comment: actually I want whole row and .val() gives only single column's value...and whatever output comes I want to place in table format

Comment: I see you want all companies right? Load all selected from the multiple <select>